# How to show my current location in Google Maps Android using google API client

Tags: android, google-maps

Hi i am new for android and in my app i want to show my current location using GoogleApi client and for this i wrote below code but current location is not showing

Map is shows like my below screen shot

Can some one help me please what is problem?

### Activity:-

```
public class GoogleApiClientClass extends AppCompatActivity implements
        OnMapReadyCallback, GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks, GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener,
        LocationListener {

    LocationRequest mLocationRequest;
    GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;

    LatLng latLng;
    GoogleMap mGoogleMap;
    SupportMapFragment mFragment;
    Marker currLocationMarker;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.maps_layout);

        mFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mFragment.getMapAsync(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap gMap) {
        mGoogleMap = gMap;
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            return;
        }
        mGoogleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        buildGoogleApiClient();
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    }

    protected synchronized void buildGoogleApiClient() {
        Toast.makeText(this, "buildGoogleApiClient", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                .build();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {

        Toast.makeText(this, "onConnected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            return;
        }
        Location mLastLocation = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(
                mGoogleApiClient);
        if (mLastLocation != null) {
            //place marker at current position
            //mGoogleMap.clear();
            latLng = new LatLng(mLastLocation.getLatitude(), mLastLocation.getLongitude());
            MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();
            markerOptions.position(latLng);
            markerOptions.title("Current Position");
            markerOptions.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_MAGENTA));
            currLocationMarker = mGoogleMap.addMarker(markerOptions);
        }

        mLocationRequest = new LocationRequest();
        mLocationRequest.setInterval(5000); //5 seconds
        mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(3000); //3 seconds
        mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_BALANCED_POWER_ACCURACY);
        //mLocationRequest.setSmallestDisplacement(0.1F); //1/10 meter
        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {
        Toast.makeText(this,"onConnectionSuspended",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
        Toast.makeText(this,"onConnectionFailed",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

        //place marker at current position
        //mGoogleMap.clear();
        if (currLocationMarker != null) {
            currLocationMarker.remove();
        }
        latLng = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());
        MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();
        markerOptions.position(latLng);
        markerOptions.title("Current Position");
        markerOptions.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_MAGENTA));
        currLocationMarker = mGoogleMap.addMarker(markerOptions);

        Toast.makeText(this,"Location Changed",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        //zoom to current position:
        CameraPosition cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder()
                .target(latLng).zoom(14).build();

        mGoogleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory
                .newCameraPosition(cameraPosition));
        //If you only need one location, unregister the listener
        //LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.removeLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, this);
    }
}
```

### manifest:-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest package="com.androidtutorialpoint.googlemapsdrawroute"
          xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <permission
        android:name="in.wptrafficanalyzer.locationpolyline.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature"/>

    <uses-permission android:name="in.wptrafficanalyzer.locationpolyline.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

        <activity
            android:name=".GoogleApiClientClass"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_maps">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <!--Testing Key-->
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
            android:value="my key" />

    </application>

</manifest>
```

### screen:-

[image]

Comment: have you turned on your gps before launching the activity

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);



    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 9) {
        StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
    }

    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);

    markers = new Hashtable<String, String>();

    googleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
            .addApi(LocationServices.API)
            .build();




}

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    googleApiClient.connect();
    super.onStart();
}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    googleApiClient.disconnect();
    super.onStop();
}

//Getting current location
private void getCurrentLocation() {
    mMap.clear();
    //Creating a location object
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {


        //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
        // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
        //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
        //                                          int[] grantResults)
        // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
        // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
        return;
    }
    Location location = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(googleApiClient);
    if (location != null) {
        //Getting longitude and latitude
        longitude = location.getLongitude();
        latitude = location.getLatitude();



        //moving the map to location
        //moveMap();
    }
}

//Function to move the map
private void moveMap() {
    //String to display current latitude and longitude
    String msg = latitude + ", " + longitude;

    //Creating a LatLng Object to store Coordinates
    LatLng latLng = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);


    //Adding marker to map
    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
            .position(latLng) //setting position
            .draggable(false) //Making the marker draggable
            .title("Current Location")
    .visible(true)); //Adding a title


    //Moving the camera
    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));

    //Animating the camera
    mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(18));

    //Displaying current coordinates in toast
    Toast.makeText(this, msg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}

@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap;
    LatLng latLng = new LatLng(-34, 151);
    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(latLng).draggable(true));
    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));
    mMap.setOnMarkerDragListener(this);
    mMap.setOnMapLongClickListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
    getCurrentLocation();
    moveMap();
}

@Override
public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {

}

@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {

}

@Override
public void onMapLongClick(LatLng latLng) {
    //Clearing all the markers
  /*  mMap.clear();

    //Adding a new marker to the current pressed position
    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
            .position(latLng)
            .draggable(false));*/

}

@Override
public void onMarkerDragStart(Marker marker) {

}

@Override
public void onMarkerDrag(Marker marker) {

}

@Override
public void onMarkerDragEnd(Marker marker) {
    //Getting the coordinates
    latitude = marker.getPosition().latitude;
    longitude = marker.getPosition().longitude;

    //Moving the map
    moveMap();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try to replace this in your onLocationChanged.

```
private void locateMyLocation(Location currentLocation) {
    mGoogleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
            .title(mContext.getResources().getString(R.string.map_user_location_title))
            .anchor(0.0f, 1.0f)
            .position(new LatLng(currentLocation.getLatitude(), currentLocation.getLongitude())));
    mGoogleMap.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(false);
    mGoogleMap.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(false);
    mGoogleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(currentLocation.getLatitude(), currentLocation.getLongitude()), 15.0f));
}
```